# Get the click event from the listview and open the video

Tags: java, android, video, android-videoview

I am making a small application, namely a custom listview, when I click on a line on the listview will open a new layout and play video online. I'm wrong every time click on the picture

[image]

Here is a video class

[image]

Here is the click event in the main activity

[image]

The one thing I want to ask is that can make the user click on a line on the listview, then the video will open in full screen (automatic screen rotation) is not? And how do you know how many users click on the number line on the listview?
Thank you everyone, look forward to helping everyone :D

p/s: Does the video view support real-time video playback? Because I making watch TV online app

Comment: share error logcat

Comment: Errow logcat 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/bw7zz6kchhzp8sm/Screen%20Shot%202017-12-04%20at%205.28.30%20PM.png?dl=0

Comment: From the logcat it seems you haven't declared `ModuleDetailActivity` in your `Manifest` file

Comment: @Signo Can you help me? I don't know. :'( 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/u8sgyj39oasrkv4/Screen%20Shot%202017-12-04%20at%205.35.46%20PM.png?dl=0

Comment: @PhucHieu error solved or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your manifest file you're missing the declaration for `ModuleDetailActivity`. Just add this line inside your `application` tag to declare the activity:

```
<activity android:name=".ModuleDetailActivity" />
```

Answer (score 0):

do check you have declared `ModuleDetailActivity` in manifest file like below

```
 <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

 <activity android:name=".ModuleDetailActivity"/>
```